# Firefox crashes during selenium script execution

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Here's my machine specs
Centos 7 .
Kernel 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64
geckodriver 0.17.0
Selenium + Java
Mozilla Firefox 52.2.0

while running the program firefox crashes by giving below error
I m running it using normal user .

```
1500138350643   Marionette      INFO    New connections will no longer be accepted
[Child 3505] WARNING: pipe error (3): Connection reset by peer: file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-52.2.0/firefox-52.2.0esr/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 322
[Child 3505] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-52.2.0/firefox-52.2.0esr/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2152
[Child 3505] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-52.2.0/firefox-52.2.0esr/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2152
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and when checked i got to know my firefox version had updated automatically and the geckodriver version i was using was not compatible.

Update your geckodriver and that should solve your problem